How to make my container fill the bottom of my page (if the page is not scrollable)
I am facing this issue, i think the answer is very simple but I can't figure it out.
First I'll explain with words :
I have a dark background, my nav is transparent (so it looks like the background) and my page container is a kind of big white card.

when the page is scrollable => the page container height hits the bottom of the page :
scrollable view
when the page is not scrollable (not enough content to make it scrollable) => there is a empty area till the bottom : not scrollable view

I checked CSS and there is no strange behavior. I tried some stuff found on the web, but it did the opposite.
here is my dom structure :


#root, html {
  background: #353333;
}
.page-container {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  column-gap: 1.5rem;
  row-gap: 1rem;
  height: fit-content;
}
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <div class="layout">
        <div class="navigation">logo, nav links ...</div>
        <div class="page-container">
          <div class="grid">
            <div>div</div>
            <div>div</div>
            <div>div</div>
            <div>div</div>
            <div>div</div>
            <div>div</div>
            <div>div</div>
            <div>div</div>
            <div>div</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>



I can't really share due to privacy policies.. If I am missing something, just ask and I will update my post
I tried to increase body & root height

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

@Paulie_D, I added a snippet. Remove some div to see that the page container doesn't fill the bottom

Would adding a min-size to the body works (100vh) ? I'm no sure to really get it

Rationale
When you run into a problem like this, it's usually wise to narrow it down to the minimal elements required, so that you can clearly see which CSS-properties are needed and which aren't.
Steps
In your example you need to do three things:

Make sure the parent containers are displayed at 100% height

Set display: flex on the parent node, in this case .layout

Set flex-grow: 1 on the nodes that need to grow


Working example


html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #353333;
  color: #ccc;
}

.layout {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.growing-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: white;
  color: #333;
}
  
<div class="layout">
  <header>This container does not grow</header>

  <main class="growing-child">
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </main>

  <footer>Optional footer</footer>
</div>



Note
If you have html and body and #root and layout, then all of them need to either be of 100% height or otherwise grow along with the content.

Thank you for your complete answer ! I was missing a div that wraps the layout, and make it impossible, it works now.

@samy.mssi you're very welcome, glad it worked. Would you mind upvoting pls?

I think what you're looking for here is sometimes referred to as the "sticky footer" pattern. This uses Flexbox to make the main content area expand to fill any empty space with any footer being pinned to the bottom of the viewport. The fantastic thing about this technique is once a page does have more content than can fit in the viewport, everything else works as you'd expect, you just scroll to read the rest of the content.
Philip Walton on his "Solved by Flexbox" site explains this technique in great detail: https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/
Looking at your HTML structure you may need to expand on the above example, or tweak your structure but I think you should be able to achieve your goal using this technique.

You can use the "min-height" property to set the page-container element, here is an example:
.page-container {
    min-height: 100vh;
}

